# Is it possible only build for dynamic packages in Builder C++?

Tags: c++builder

When I compile from Builder C++ IDE, the compiler create two kind of files, one for static linking and another dynamic packages.
I never use the static linking. Is it possible to deactivate the compilation for static files?  It would save half of time.

Environment: Rad Studio Berlin, CLANG as C++ compiler.

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit? The Clang compilers for 32 bit and 64 bit are different.

Comment: The compiler is CLANG 32 bits

Comment: I have over 200 cpp files. The compiler compiles each cpp file twice, one for static linking and another for dynamic linking. I only need the files dynamic linking, so I would expect that it takes half of time.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but when I compile, I can see how the compiler loads all cpp files, after some minutes, it creates the BPL file. Then, it starts again, it loads all cpp files and compiles again. In the bin folder, I can see the OBJ file for each cpp file, and under the "staticobjs" subfolder, I can see the same OBJ files but compiled for static linking.

Comment: Also, it is explained at Embarcadero web: "For packages, RAD Studio also creates a static version of your C++ object files"

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/C%2B%2B_Object_File_(*.obj,_*.o)